# Using integer values instead of double values

Tags: flutter

Why do everyone write decimals in the following examples,
as I know there is no difference for compiler and runtime when using integer values?

```
TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)
```

Comment: They just like writing in double values since you can set the sizes with double values. You can also write in integer values if you want. Writing 12.0 and 12 would pretty much be the same.

Comment: @Uni Have you ever seen size values like 12.3 ? I mean no one realy uses double values in such constructors but they still write it like double.

Comment: I've never seen one for fontsize but then I do use double values for padding and border radius like 12.5 or something like that. For some reason, some people write still write 12.0 and not 12. It guess its just preference